# Highlight duplicate cell values in different colours

Tags: excel

I'm using conditional formatting to highlight duplicate cells, but I have up to 5 instances of a duplicated value. How can I apply a separate colour to each duplicated cell?

So if I have 5 instances of ABC123, how can the first instance be red, the second green, the third blue, fourth yellow, fifth orange (or whatever colours)?

Answer (score 0):

I take it this is in Excel 2007? In earlier versions you can only have three different conditions.

The way I'd do this is to introduce a 'helper' column, containing a formula which provides the count of duplicates *up to that row number*:

Say you have your list (including dupes) in range A1:A10, and in column B1:B10, a formula of the form `=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)` through `=COUNTIF($A$1:A10,A10)`, you'd have

```
      A    B
------------
1     4    1
2     2    1
3     4    2
4     3    1
5     1    1
6     2    2
7     4    3
8     2    3
9     2    4
10    1    2
```

I don't know your exact Conditional Formatting requirements, but you can now use 5 nested `IF` formulas to take account of not only the fact that something is a dupe (cell in `B` is >= 2), but also the count of the dupe.